# I cannot read csv file as pandas dataframe (anymore)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have just changed laptop (from Windows to Mac) and after reinstalling anaconda/spyder I have tried to run the same code that reads a csv file as a pandas dataframe.

I have been using: pd.read_csv (path file)

```
pd.read_csv("/User/Documents/etc...csv")
```

but the code gets stuck. It runs for several minutes and afterwards the console displays:

```
"Errno 5" Input/output error: '/User/Documents/....'.
```

Do you have an idea of which reason could be behind this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
from pathlib import Path
pd.read_csv(Path("User/Documents/etc/file.csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your csv file is not correct format. May be use a spacial character. so you can try this code.

```
pd.read_csv("/User/Documents/etc...csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 0):

use two forward // instead of one 
like this 
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv("C//User/Documents/etc..//filename.csv")